# Inject audio and broadcast/stream over internet

Tags: audio, streaming, radio

I like to attach an FM tuner like Si4703 to raspberry pi 3 and want to rebroadcast particular frequency (FM) over the internet (I want to listen to local FM when I'm in my office since I don't get a good signal in my office).

How can I do this? the Si4703 receiver module has 3.5mm audio jack output and I don't know, how to set up the raspberry pi to receive the audio from 3.5mm audio jack and broadcast over the internet.

For broadcasting, I am thinking of Icecast although I haven't tried Icecast in raspberry pi.
[image]

Comment: Not sure that's legal in any country that follows copyright law!  Why not see if the station has an mp3 feed that you can listen to?  e.g. http://www.radiofeeds.co.uk/mp3.asp for UK stations

Comment: You can't violate copyright laws by eg., listening to a recording you have made of a public broadcast and this is the same principle. Anyway: You need a USB sound card dongle w/ a 3.5mm input (which is most of them).